# Xpath query to get the ancester nodes based on element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to find all the element names which follow the below two rules.

1. elements should have the `<set>erase</set>`

2. if two or more elements have the `<set>erase</set>` in hierarchy (Ex: `<b>` and `<d>` both have `<set>erase</set>`) then only the parent node name has to be printed(ie `<b>` in this case).

So the required result for below xml needs to be :

> b , y , p

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <set>erase</set>
        <d>
        <set>erase</set>
        </d>
    </b>

    <c>
        <x>
        </x>
    </c>

    <e>

        <y>
                    <set>erase</set>
            <q>
            </q>
        </y>
        <z>
            <p>
            <set>erase</set>
            </p>
        </z>
    </e>
</a>
```

When I use the `query = (//set[contains(.,'erase')])[1]` I get only node `b` in result set.
When I use the `query = //set[contains(.,'erase')]` I get all nodesList `b,d,y,p` in result set.

Can anyone help me find the query to result in nodeList `b` ,  `y`  and `p`.

Here is the java code snippet I used.

```
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
    String query = "//set[contains(.,'erase')]";
            XPathExpression expr=null;
    try {
        expr = xpath.compile(query);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        Object result = null;
    try {
        result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;


    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        String x = "";
        Node n = nodes.item(i).getParentNode();
        x=n.getNodeName();
        while(!n.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(request.getClass().getSimpleName())){
            if ((n = n.getParentNode())!=null){
                x=n.getNodeName()+"."+x;
            }
        }



        System.out.println("Path: "+x);
```

output:

```
a.b
a.b.d
a.e.y
a.e.z.p
```

Could anyone help me figure out the query which results in only `a.b , a.e.y  and a.e.z.p`
Let me know if you need more details. or any other use-case.

Comment: user1207560: You have accepted a wrong answer -- just use the proposed expression in your code to verify that it doesn't select the wanted elements. Why this is so is explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One expression that selects exactly the wanted elements is**:

```
      //*[set[. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
         and
          not(ancestor::*
                 [set
                    [. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                 ]
              )
          ]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:for-each select=
         "//*[set[. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
             and
              not(ancestor::*
                     [set
                        [. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                     ]
                  )
              ]">

          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This transformation, when applied on the provided by Sean B. Durkin XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <set>erase</set>
        <set>
            <a/>erase
        </set>
        <d>
            <set>erase</set>
        </d>
    </b>
    <c>
        <x>         </x>
    </c>
    <e>
        <y>
            <set>erase</set>
            <q>             </q>
        </y>
        <z>
            <p>
                <set>erase</set>
            </p>
        </z>
    </e>
</a>
```

**evaluates the XPath expression above and outputs the names of the selected elements -- the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
b
y
p
```

**Do note** that the following two expressions are quite incorrect:

```
*[set[text()='erase']][not(ancestor::*[set[text()='erase']])]
```

Or:

```
*[set[text()='erase']][ancestor::*[set[text()!='erase']]]
```

**These two expressions suffer from more than one problem**:

1. They are *relative* expressions and regardless with which initial context they are applied, they cannot select all wanted elements in an hierarchy with undefined depth and structure.
2. `set[text()='erase']` selects not only an element of the form:

...

```
<set>erase</set>
```

but also elements of the form:

```
<set>
xyz
 <a/>erase</set>
```

.3. Similarly:

```
set[text()!='erase']
```

selects elements of the form:

```
<set>
xyz
 <a/>erase</set>
```

Comment: This may be a stale question, but I am having doubts about Novatchev's answer. If you apply the following document to Novatchev's self-test program ("XSLT - based verification"), then the wrong output is produced (at least as far as I understand the questioner's requirements): I can't put the counter-example in a comment, because it is too big, so I have attached it to my answer.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: Thank you for the good example XML document. I have edited my answer with an XPath expression that selects the correct and expected set of nodes.

Comment: Just wondering... Could "[. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]" be simplified to "['erase' and not(node()[2])]"? Also you seem to prefer to test sequence length with an indexing predicate, over using the count() function? Is this preference just a matter of style? or are there real benefits (clarity, performance etc.) to the predicate method?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: No, in  `['erase' and not(node()[2])]` the first argument of the `and` operator is a non-empty string and it is converted to `true()` -- quite different result from `. = 'erase'`. As for testing that there isn't second node in a node-set, this is much more efficient than using `count()` -- imagine having to count 1000 nodes just to see that this number is > 1.

Comment: @Dimitre: Just a small question. If I want to select <set> elements instead of their parents <a>/<b>/<c> .... How would I do that?  I tried //set[contains(.,'erase')]  will select all.. but how to ignore the descendents ?

Comment: @user1207560: `//set` selects all `set` elements in the XML document. `//set[.='erase']` selects all `set` elements in the XML document whose string value is the string `"erase"`. Get the XPath Visualizer at: http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html  and play with it.

Comment: @Dimitri: Yeah I did that but iam looking for a way to ignore the redundant nodes containing set elements containing 'erase'. Basically ignore the descendents. Filter logic to ignore nodes if its anscesters have set='erase'

Comment: @user1207560: Please, ask a new question, give a good example and explain well -- comments aren't convenient for exchanging code.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev:Please refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9440119/xpath-query-to-select-all-elements-ignoring-descendants-based-on-criteria

Answer (score 0):

This is my second attempt:

```
//*[                    set[count(node())=1 and text()='erase'] and
      not( ancestor::*[ set[count(node())=1 and text()='erase']])
   ]
```

This selection passes the test case shown in my first answer.

Answer (score -1):

The following XPath selects the nodes that you want:

```
//*[set[text()='erase']][not(ancestor::*[set[text()='erase']])]
```

I tested it with the following stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()" />

    <xsl:template match="//*[set[text()='erase']][not(ancestor::*[set[text()='erase']])]">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="self::*|ancestor::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>) </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produced the output

```
(a.b.) (a.e.y.) (a.e.z.p.)
```

Comment: @user1207560, per Dimitre's answer, I've modified this so that all desired nodes are selected by a single expression (added `//` to front).

Answer (score -1):

Or this slight tweek on Harpo's answer?:

```
*[set[text()='erase']][ancestor::*[set[text()!='erase']]]
```

Following my comment on Novatchev's answer, please consider useful test case:

This is a change from the questionioner's demo document. I have added another  node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <set>erase</set>
        <set><a/>erase</set>
        <d>
        <set>erase</set>
        </d>
    </b>
    <c>
        <x>
        </x>
    </c>
    <e>
        <y>
        <set>erase</set>
            <q>
            </q>
        </y>
        <z>
            <p>
            <set>erase</set>
            </p>
        </z>
    </e>
</a>
```

Answer should be

```
b
y
p
```

Comment: Only this doesn't select anything.  The second clause says, give me only nodes with an ancestor that has a `set` child *not* containing the text "erase".  In this document, all of the `set` elements do.

Comment: Hmm.. This did not select the elements required. The reason I see this did not work is that you have set != on a the text value 'erase' and not on the node. To put @harpo 's solution in words first he selected all the nodes that have <set>erase</set> then from the result he added an extra condtion to remove all the nodes that does not have a ancesters with <set>erase</set>.

Comment: Well what an interesting language XSLT is! There are two people who always have the right answer: Novatchev and Kaye. Today I got corrected by both of them in one day. I guess its my lucky day for self-improvement :-)

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: You'd be *actively* lucky if you buy and read a book by Michael Kay (correctly spelled). See some links to these books here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: Thanks for the good catch. I updated my answer promptly and now your provided XML document isn't "counter-example" any more... :) Therefore, could you, please, update the now wrong statement in your question? :)