# Xpath query to select all elements ignoring descendants based on criteria

Tags: xpath

I am trying to select all the `<set>erase</set>` elements such that if two or more elements have the `<set>erase</set>` in hierarchy (Ex: `<b>` and `<d>` both have `<set>erase</set>`) then only the  element in parent node name has to be selected(ie `<b>` in this case).

Sample xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <set>erase</set>
        <d>
            <set>erase</set>
        </d>
    </b>

    <c>
        <x></x>
    </c>

    <e>
        <y>
            <set>erase</set>
            <q></q>
        </y>
        <z>
            <p>
                <set>erase</set>
            </p>
        </z>
    </e>
</a>
```

When I use the `query = //set[contains(.,'erase')]` I get all `<set>erase</set>` of nodesList `b,d,y,p` in result set.

I need help in framing the query to select `<set>erase</set>`   of   `b` ,  `y`  and `p`.

Comment: I don't think your requirements are clear. Why wouldn't `a` be selected, based on what you describe?

Comment: @lwburk: Sorry my bad. I corrected the sample xml I gave.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xpath query to get the ancester nodes based on element value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271001/xpath-query-to-get-the-ancester-nodes-based-on-element-value)

Comment: user1207560: I really don't understand what is new in your question. ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is *the same* solution**:

**One XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted elements is**:

```
          //*[set[. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
             and
              not(ancestor::*
                     [set
                        [. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                     ]
                  )
              ]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
         <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

         <xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:for-each select=
             "//*[set[. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                 and
                  not(ancestor::*
                         [set
                            [. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                         ]
                      )
                  ]">

              <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
              <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <set>erase</set>
        <d>
            <set>erase</set>
        </d>
    </b>
    <c>
        <x></x>
    </c>
    <e>
        <y>
            <set>erase</set>
            <q></q>
        </y>
        <z>
            <p>
                <set>erase</set>
            </p>
        </z>
    </e>
</a>
```

**The contained XPath expression is evaluated and the names of the selected elements are output -- correctly and as expected**:

```
b
y
p
```

If you need to select the `set` children of the selected above elements, just append the above XPath expression with `/set`:

```
          //*[set[. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
             and
              not(ancestor::*
                     [set
                        [. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                     ]
                  )
              ]
               /set
```

**Again, XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
         <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

         <xsl:template match="/">
             <xsl:copy-of select=
             "//*[set[. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                 and
                  not(ancestor::*
                         [set
                            [. = 'erase' and not(node()[2])]
                         ]
                      )
                  ]
                   /set
                  "/>
         </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This transformation just evaluates the above XPath expression and copies to the output the correctly selected three `set` elements**:

```
<set>erase</set>
<set>erase</set>
<set>erase</set>
```

Comment: I wanted the second part where we return the <set>erase</set>. The reason behind this is that I am using JXPath to return me the pointer to the <set> which have 'erase'.